# Writing assembly code for raspberry Pi, MinGW error

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi, mingw

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/ok01.html#note5) and I have gotten to the point where I need to 'make' compiled image to get it into pi, but I am getting following error:

```
mkdir build/
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Makefile:57: recipe for target 'build/' failed
mingw32-make: *** [build/] Error 1
```

The makefile is available [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/downloads.html#template) in the template. Lines 56 + 57 look like this:

```
$(BUILD):
    mkdir $@
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it? I am new to this and following the step by step guide :/ Thank you!

Comment: what if you just type `mkdir build/` in windows command line? Do you still get the error?

Comment: thank you for your tip, I tried and it was incorrect because of the slash. So I corrected it and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to igagis' coment I have discovered what the problem was that: `mkdir build/` is incorrect command because of the slash sign '/'.
In the make file, the variable target is defined as: `BUILD = build/` because it is later used as a path. I fixed line 57 as following:

```
$(BUILD):
    mkdir build
```

and the code now compiles as intended.